# Submit Button bypasses Captcha security

Tags: php, html

I have been having spam through my contact form, to cut a long story short my captcha is not working. I have used Sweet Captcha (http://sweetcaptcha.com/) as this offers more user friendly approach. When a user clicks on submit it posts to my email as normal, however it does not require the user to preform the captcha, therefore resulting in spam from Viagra companies etc... Would you be able to have a quick look and see where I'm going wrong. Any help is appreciated as always.

Thanks

Andy

```
   <?php

// require sweetcaptcha php sdk, don't forget to set up your credentials first
require_once('sweetcaptcha.php');

if (empty($_POST)) {
// print sweetcaptcha in your form
?>
```

```
    <p class="name">
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Your Name"       required="required" requiredmessage="Name is required."/>

    </p>

    <p class="email">
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="mail@example.com" required="required"/>

    </p>

    <p class="web">
        <input type="text" name="web" id="web" placeholder="www.example.com   *Not Mandatory*" />

    </p>        

    <p class="text">
        <textarea name="text" placeholder="How can I help?" required="required"></textarea>
    </p>

       <!-- implemet sweetcaptcha -->
       <?php echo $sweetcaptcha->get_html(); ?>
       <!-- continue with your form -->
       <input type="submit" />
       </form>


 <?php
 } else { 

// looks like someone has submitted a form, let's validate it
if (isset($_POST['sckey']) and isset($_POST['scvalue']) and $sweetcaptcha-  >check(array('sckey' => $_POST['sckey'], 'scvalue' => $_POST['scvalue'])) == "true") {
// success! your form was validated
// do what you like next ...
echo "Success! carry on if you will";
}
else {
// alas! the validation has failed, the user might be a spam bot or just got the result  wrong
// handle this as you like
echo "Boohoo! captcha validation failed!";
}

}

?>
```

Comment: I don't know, but this `-  >` looks kind of suspicious to me...

Comment: I wouldn't use it at all anymore: https://blog.sucuri.net/2015/06/sweetcaptcha-service-used-to-distribute-adware.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

switch to reCaptcha, or some alternative captcha system, it seems..

your code seems to be right (i could nitpick about == vs === and isset/empty vs array_key_exists and _SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"], but im lazy), so... either the check() call is bugging up, or sweetchaptcha is broken..

as a scary funfact, XRumer/Botmasterlabs have cracked reCaptcha and the PhpBB/Gmail/Yahoo/Hotmail registration captcha over the years REPEATEDLY (at least until ~2010 , i haven't kept updated with their changelogs since..)

Comment: Thank you for your replies, I checked the METHOD and realized I made a stupid rookie error. I read some threads about Captcha security and yes scary how simple these large web companies get hacked. Thanks for help...